# converting mysql database to sql server

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

i have a mysql database:

```
/*
MySQL Data Transfer
Source Host: 10.0.0.5
Source Database: jnetdata
Target Host: 10.0.0.5
Target Database: jnetdata
Date: 5/26/2009 12:27:33 PM
*/

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for chavrusas
-- ----------------------------
CREATE TABLE `chavrusas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `date_created` datetime default NULL,
  `luser_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `ruser_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `luser_type` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `ruser_type` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `SessionDay` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `SessionTime` datetime default NULL,
  `WeeklyReminder` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `reminder_phone` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `calling_card` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `notes` mediumtext,
  `ended` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `end_date` datetime default NULL,
  `initiated_by_student` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `initiated_by_volunteer` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `student_general_reason` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `volunteer_general_reason` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `student_reason` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `volunteer_reason` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `student_nli` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `volunteer_nli` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `jnet_initiated` tinyint(1) default '0',
  `belongs_to` varchar(50) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5913 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for tbluseravailability
-- ----------------------------
CREATE TABLE `tbluseravailability` (
  `availability_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `weekday_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timeslot_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`availability_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10865 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for tblusers
-- ----------------------------
CREATE TABLE `tblusers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `password` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `first` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `last` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `gender` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `address_2` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `emailnotes` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `Home_Phone` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `Office_Phone` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `Cell_Phone` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `Contact_Preference` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `Birthdate` datetime default NULL,
  `Age` varchar(255
```

and it goes on for about 10mb

i need to convert it to ms sql, how do i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i remember that i used this small tool to convert maybe it may help you, check [here.](http://gathadams.com/2008/02/07/convert-mysql-to-ms-sql-server/)
Another tool [MySQL-to-MSSQL](http://www.convert-in.com/sql2mss.htm) is more powerful.

Answer (score 3):

Some options:

- [Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant 2008 for MySQL v1.0 CTP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0e6168b0-2d0c-4076-96c2-60bd25294a8e&displaylang=en)
- [Guide to Migrating from MySQL to SQL Server 2008](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/C/2/7C20B070-BFF8-44B4-BD7D-1B03DF50F924/MigrateMySQLtoSQLServer2008.docx)
- [Migrating from MySQL to SQL Server 2005](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/c/8/ec8d5025-7ef7-4dcc-a9f3-9c297cf5350e/MigrateMySQLtoSQLServer.docx)

Haven't used this, so can't comment on it's effectiveness:

- [Migrate MySQL to Microsoft SQL Server](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/migrate-mysql-to-mssql.aspx)

Might be useful (if you don't already have it):

- [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=08E52AC2-1D62-45F6-9A4A-4B76A8564A2B&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant 2008 for MySQL v1.0 CTP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=0e6168b0-2d0c-4076-96c2-60bd25294a8e)

Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) 2008 is a toolkit that dramatically cuts the effort, cost, and risk of migrating from MySQL to SQL Server 2008 and SQL Azure. SSMA 2008 for MySQL v1.0 CTP1 provides an assessment of migration efforts as well as automates schema and data migration.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SQL Examiner Suite 2010](http://www.sqlaccessories.com/SQL_Examiner/MySQL_Schema_Compare.aspx)